# npm ERR! 404 Unpublished by undefined on 2022-08-08T09:20:35.527Z

Tags: javascript, npm, npm-package

When I run <npm view e-biz-znnf versions --json> by cmd, npm shows the following error:

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Unpublished by undefined on 2022-08-08T09:20:35.527Z
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'e-biz-znnf' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
{
  "error": {
    "code": "E404",
    "summary": "Unpublished by undefined on 2022-08-08T09:20:35.527Z",
    "detail": "\n 'e-biz-znnf' is not in the npm registry.\nYou should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)\n\nNote that you can also install from a\ntarball, folder, http url, or git url."
  }
}
```

The error means the package of a certain version wasn't published.

And when I check the package version list in the Verdaccio, the time node of the package's json information shows the unpublished node (1.1.26-alpha.0) which was already published.

But the time of the published version is different from the unpublished one.

The package is on a private Verdaccio server.

And when I delete the unpublished node in the package.json file on the Verdaccio server, it don't report the error.

Why there are unpublished versions? How dit it happen?

```
{
    "versions": {
        "2.0.0": {
            "version": "2.0.0",
            "description": "deleted extra fields"
        },
        "1.1.26-alpha.0": {
            "version": "1.1.26-alpha.0",
            "types": "./types/index.d.ts",
            "scripts": {},
            "name": "e-biz-znnf",
            "main": "index.js",
            "license": "ISC",
            "dist": {
                "tarball": "http://***/e-biz-znnf/-/e-biz-znnf-1.1.26-alpha.0.tgz",
                "shasum": "***",
                "integrity": "sha512-***"
            },
            "description": "tools packages",
            "contributors": [],
            "author": "",
            "_npmVersion": "6.14.17",
            "_nodeVersion": "14.20.0",
            "_id": "e-biz-znnf@1.1.26-alpha.0"
        },
        "1.1.25": {
            "version": "1.1.25",
            "description": "deleted extra fields"
        }
    },
    "users": {},
    "time": {
        "unpublished": {
            "versions": [
                "1.1.26-alpha.0"
            ],
            "time": "2022-08-08T09:20:35.527Z"
        },
        "modified": "2023-01-30T03:17:32.951Z",
        "created": "2022-08-08T09:18:19.876Z",
        "2.0.0": "2023-01-30T03:17:32.951Z",
        "1.1.26-alpha.0": "2022-08-08T09:18:20.123Z",
        "1.1.25": "2022-07-26T07:25:00.977Z"
    },
    "readme": "ERROR: No README data found!",
    "name": "e-biz-znnf",
    "dist-tags": {
        "latest": "2.0.0"
    },
    "_rev": "295-f8da7bf7f8a7099a",
    "_id": "e-biz-znnf",
    "_attachments": {}
}
```

Comment: please do not use images for errors

Comment: Frustrating, as I have the same error (with versions or version), and no good answer…
Even if I publish a new version, it still blocks on this error.
On Verdaccio's Raw Manifest, I once saw "unpublished" versions, but after two releases, they are gone, but it still errors out.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to run this command

```
npm view versions --json
```

it will give the output you want

Comment: Yes, exactly I do like this: npm view <packageName> versions --json. But it reports the error above.